# Searching for an explanation for a trigger SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the trigger below and am trying to understand what it is supposed to do. I am not a dba but am trying to understand the script below.

Does it mean every time an update (insert, delete, update) happens with the IT01_Incorporates table, the DateUpdated column is updated with the current date? 
I actually would like to know, by applying the trigger below, when is the DateUpdated column supposed to be updated? insert, delete and update?

I also would like to understand the meaning of : set nocount on.

Thank you very much

DateUpdated column is datetime type

```
CREATE trigger [dbo].[TR_IT01_Update] 
on [dbo].[IT01_Incorporates]
for update
as
set nocount on
begin

    update  IT01_Incorporates
    set DateUpdated = getdate()
    where   exists (
    select  1 from inserted where incorpuid = IT01_Incorporates.incorpuid
    )

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say the following SQL statement was added to a .NET program one year ago:

```
UPDATE IT01_Incorporates set field1=@Field1, field2=@Field2, Field3=@Field3 where id=@id
```

Lets say one of your DBA colleagues altered the table yesterday as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE IT01_Incorporates ADD DateUpdated datetime
```

Instead of modifying the code; he/she may create a trigger as a temporary measure to ensure that DateUpdated is also updated with every update.

Comment: It is very clear now. Thank you very much every one for your help

Comment: No problem.  Please upvote and/or accept if it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the script, you will see in the header lines, the clause `for update`.  This indicates that it is for update only.

To make for inserts and updates, you would have to change it to say `for insert, update`.  You could also add `, delete` to make it fire on DELETEs as well, but the trigger will not work in that case because there would no longer be any record to UPDATE.